# Get search results in a different language locale

Tags: google-chrome, search, language, duckduckgo

Using Google Chrome with the search term `DAO tutorial C#.` Have tested both [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?) and [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/).

In both cases one of the top results is [Creating a Data Access Layer (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) which contains the locale code `en-us`. The result is an indecipherable date `04/05/2010`. To make sure of the date, I manually replace `en-us` with `en-gb` in the URL and the date changes to `05/04/2010`, so I know the article was written in April 2010.

Google's search settings for language can be accessed at `Google Search > Settings > Language`, and is set to `English` (there is no "English (United Kingdom)" option).

DuckDuckGo's search settings for language can be accessed at `DuckDuckGo > Settings > Language`, and this one is set to `English (Unied Kingdom)`.

Finally `Chrome > Settings > Advanced > Language` is set to `English (United Kingdom)` and no other language is listed.

Is there any way to force Chrome, and the search engine I use, to request only `en-gb` pages?